# How to select Admin View or User View in the same page?

Tags: java, jsp, authentication

i got a problem when redirect a page between admin and user level.This is my ***checklogin.jsp*** file:

```
<%
String name = request.getParameter("username");
String pass = request.getParameter("password");
try {
    Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
    Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;databaseName=demoLoginAdminUser", "sa", "sa");
    Statement st = con.createStatement();
    ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery("select * from reg");
    int x = 0;
    while (rs.next()) {
        if ((rs.getString("username").equals(name)) && rs.getString("password").equals(pass)) {
            String stp = rs.getString("uType");
            if (stp.equals("admin")) {
                x = 1;
                break;
            } else {
                x = 2;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    if (x == 2) {
        response.sendRedirect("student.jsp");
    } else if (x == 1) {
        response.sendRedirect("admin.jsp");
    } else {
        out.println("Either you enter Invalid UserName or Password! Please Try Again");
%>
        <jsp:include page="index.html" />
    <%}
        } catch (Exception e) {
            out.println(e);
        }
        session.setAttribute("username", name);
    %>
```

i already redirect admin to ***admin.jsp*** and user to ***student.jsp***.
Now i want login to ***home.jsp*** page. 
Example, login with admin then ***home.jsp*** will display **Edit** button, if not, this button will be hidden.This is picture what i want 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/GA3u0.jpg

so this is the logic which is used for redirect admin and user to ***admin.jsp***  and ***student.jsp***. But I want to use just one page and if you are admin, some buttons will be enable, if not that button will be hidden.

Thanks for reading. i hope somebody help me this. :)

Comment: Try to adhere with `MVC` architecture. using scriptlets are highly discouraged over the decades

Comment: thank you, can you give me your solution with this problems? i'm trying to find new way to fix this.

Comment: Can you pls elaborate your question . i couldnt understand your problem . pls edit your question to make it more clear

Comment: ok i was sent link of picture demo. can u understand what i means?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As San Krish said, you **really should** replace this JSP with a servlet that could implement the same logic and either redirect at the end - as you currently do - or forward to a JSP page.

But anyway, you should not rely on a simple redirection to make the difference between user and admin. The usual way would be to use one or more session(s) attribute(s) to store the login name and/or the role of the user. Then in the JSP page you test the name or better role to decide if you display or not buttons. It will be better not to display them than simply hide them, because user can always see source HTML in the browser.

And you should test when you process a form submission that user in session is allowed to do it and not rely on the fact that a non admin should not have seen button : request can easily be forged.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply put an flag into the session:

***checklogin.jsp***

```
session.setAttribute("isAdmin", stp.equals("admin"));
session.setAttribute("username", name);
```

***home.jsp*** with taglib

```
<%@taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>

<c:if test="${isAdmin}">
  <button>Admin Action</button>
</c:if>
```

***home.jsp*** without taglib

```
<%if((Boolean)(session.getAttribute("isAdmin")) {%>
  <button>Admin Action</button>
<%}%>
```